# Git Bash cannot find mysql.exe in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, bash, git

When running the winpty mysql -u root -p command I get "winpty: error: cannot start 'mysql': Not found in PATH". The file is there under C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin and the path has been added as a windows system path variable as well. I was able to successfully log in using the MySQL command line client but I can't using Git Bash. I am basically trying to create a new database for my Laravel project.

Comment: try export the path explicitly for git bash window

Comment: I did that it says winpty: error: cannot start 'mysql': Not found in PATH